# Caching navbar links in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, caching, razor

I have an ASP.NET Core app that displays different navbar links based on the role of the user.

It first checks if the user is signed in. If yes, the name and role are retrieved from the database. The navigation bar links are then rendered using a switch statement on the role. This is in my *_LoginPartial.cshtml* that I include in my *_Layout.cshtml*:

```
@inject SignInManager<AppUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<AppUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    string name = UserManager.Users
        .Where(u => u.Id == UserManager.GetUserId(User))
        .Select(u => u.AppUser.FirstName + " " + u.AppUser.LastName)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    var usr = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    string role = (await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(usr))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 d-lg-flex justify-content-center flex-fill ">
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark text-uppercase font-size-xlarge font-weight-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
        </li>
        @switch (role)
        {
            case "Student": 
                <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Exams" asp-controller="Schedules" asp-action="Index">Exams</a>
                </li>
                @* More student-specific links here *@
                break;

            case "Instructor":
                <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Programs" asp-controller="Programs" asp-action="Index">Programs</a>
               </li> 
                @* More instructor-specific links here *@
                break;

            case "Administrator":
                @* Admin-specific links here *@ 
                break;
        }
    </ul>
}
```

I would like to cache these links to avoid fetching the role and name of the user from the database every time for every user. Since this code is part of the layout file, it executes for every page.

How can I use the cache tag helper to cache the list of navigation links that vary by role? I have tried something like this:

```
<cache vary-by="@role">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 d-lg-flex justify-content-center flex-fill ">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark text-uppercase font-size-xlarge font-weight-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
            </li>
        @switch (role) {
        ...
    </ul>
</cache>
```

However, I'm not quite sure if this offers any performance advantage as this does not prevent the round-trips to the database for reading the name and role of the user. Is there any workaround that I could use to cache these navbar links that vary by role? I'm not using any distributed cache services for my app. Or should this be done by injecting `IMemoryCache`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to reduce the calls to the database, I can see the next options:

1. You need to have the *role* saved somewhere - e.g. by using Session.
2. or Change the output cache to vary by the user:

```
<cache vary-by-user>
```

3. or Use claims instead of roles. The claims list can be retrieved from *ClaimsPrincipal* without any database query.